# Which biological process causes the feeling of having "Butterflies in the body"?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience

If someone is under stress, he or she may feel a strange feeling in the belly; it can be said that he or she feels that butterflies spread through the belly.

For other emotional reactions like being in love, similar, but different feelings can be caused.

What causes this symptoms? Is it because of the muscle tension varies, is it an electric current through the nerves?

Comment: "Butterflies" are caused by adrenaline (or nor-epinephrine) released by stress. It is one of the first stress hormones released. Love is a bit different. This question is very broad, and you can easily google part of it and show your research. If you narrow this down, and add your research, I'd be happy to withdraw mt close vote.

Comment: Why we can feel the adrenalin or nor-epinephrine release?

Comment: Do some research. I wasn't writing for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

These sorts of behaviors are mediated through activation of the sympathetic pathway of the [autonomic nervous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomic_nervous_system).

Comment: it would greatly strengthen your answer if you could expand it a bit...FYI